# 7 ice-cream balls, 2 people, and each one chooses 3 balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've bumped into a question in probability that I reach some kind of contradiction when solving it.

The question: "In a kitchen there're 3 vanilla balls, 2 strawberry balls, and 2 banana balls. Dan and Dana take each one 3 balls.

Let's mark:

- X - num of tastes of ice-cream Dan eats.
- Y - num of vanilla balls that Dana eats.

Find the table of probabilities."

My solution attempt:
[image]

I marked with yellow color the contradiction I get...

- for probability space I chose $\binom{7}{3}$ to find in how many ways I can choose 3 balls of ice cream.
- for $P(X=1,Y=0)$ in numerator - $\binom{2}{1}$ ways to choose between Banana taste and Strawberry taste to have 2 balls, and $\binom{2}{1}$ to choose the third ball from either Banana or Strawberry.
- on other hand, $P(X=1)$ has 1 in numerator because there's only one way Dan is having 1 taste - only if he takes the 3 Vanilla balls.

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: $P(X=1)$ actually has 4 in numerator because although there's only one way for Dan having 1 taste, Dana still has 4 choices.

Comment: @grixor cool! furthermore, I just noticed that inside the table (not the Marginal distribution area) - I've to change the probability space to $\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{3}$ because In other way I dont relate to the choosing of the second person. In this way everything work out!

I will add a full answer when I'm done. thanks

Comment: you're welcome! Yeah let us know when you're done!

Answer (score 1):

If Dana chooses no vanilla balls, there are four balls left for Dan to choose from, and he has $1$ way to taste exactly one flavour from these: he could choose three vanilla balls.

$\mathsf P(Y=0)=\binom 4 3/\binom 7 3~,~ \mathsf P(X=1\mid Y=0)=1/\binom 4 3$

$$\mathsf P(X=1, Y=0) = \frac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{7}{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{\binom{4}{3}} = \frac 1 {\binom 7 3} \\ \mathsf P(X=2, Y=0) = \frac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{7}{3}}\cdot\frac{\binom 3 2}{\binom 4 3} = \frac{\binom 3 2}{\binom 7 3}$$